# Build spring hello world with gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I am following this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/. I have created the java files and directory tree indicated and have the following `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories { 
    mavenCentral() 
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.14'
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
}

jar {
    archiveBaseName = 'gs-gradle'
    archiveVersion =  '0.1.0'
}
```

and when I run `gradle bulid` I get:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve joda-time:joda-time:2.10.14.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve joda-time:joda-time:2.10.14.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.10.14/joda-time-2.10.14.pom'.
            > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
```

I am using ubuntu and my gradle version is

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-08-17 09:59:03 UTC
Revision:     a773786b58bb28710e3dc96c4d1a7063628952ad

Kotlin:       1.5.21
Groovy:       3.0.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          16.0.1 (Private Build 16.0.1+9-Ubuntu-120.04)
OS:           Linux 5.15.0-30-generic amd64
```

Comment: Rather than following that guide, do what all of us do and use start.spring.io to generate a project skeleton.

Comment: Your build looks fine, I've tried running it locally and I get `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`. It seems to be an issue with your Java trust-store.

Try upgrading the jvm `sudo apt-get install openjdk-17-jdk` .